# Nuxt nested pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Having this directories:

```
|-- pages
      |--page1
      |     |--index.vue
      |     |--child1.vue
      |     |--child2.vue
      |
      |--page2
```

I am navigating to `localhost:3000/page1` and `pages/page1/index.vue` is being loaded.

Now I want to place two links inside `index.vue` so I can render the children components inside its parent `index.vue`

index.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <h1>I am the parent view</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NuxtLink to="page1/child1">Child</NuxtLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NuxtLink to="page1/child2">Child 2</NuxtLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <NuxtChild  />
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    
}
</script>
```

child1.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
      <h5>child1</h5>
    </v-container>
  </template>
```

child2.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
      <h5>child2</h5>
    </v-container>
  </template>
```

however when I click the links, I get redirected to `localhost:3000/page1/child1` so I lose the layout from parent.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you using Nuxt 2 or 3?

Comment: "nuxt": "^2.15.8",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following changes:

1. Rename and move `pages/page1/index.vue` to `pages/page1.vue`
2. Make all links absolute. For example, `"page1/child1"` must become `"/page1/child1"`
3. (Optional) If you want to display some content in NuxtChild when no child
   route is selected, then place this content in `pages/page1/index.vue`

Comment: This works, but why do i need to alter my directory structure for making it work? Is there any other way that allow me to keep my original paths?

Answer (score 0):

`pages/page1.vue` seems to be missing.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>I am the parent view</h1>
    <NuxtChild />
  </div>
</template>
```