# Nested pages in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have structute like

```
/pages/
      section/
             index.vue
             out[id].vue
```

index.vue has side menu with `id`s. How to render `out[id].vue` inside `index` ?

Like [Nuxt nested pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811907/nuxt-nested-pages) but in Nuxt3.

Can I nest not child page?

Comment: Try creating a page `pages/section.vue` instead of `pages/section/index.vue`. And use `<NuxtPage>` inside it.

Comment: @Tristan it works. but not as i wanted..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works with

```
/pages/
      section.vue
      section/
             index.vue
             out[id].vue
```

In `section.vue` wrap in layout.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtLink to="section/">index</NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink to="section/out1">out1</NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink to="section/out2">out2</NuxtLink>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to display nested routes with `<NuxtPage>`.

[source](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#nested-routes)

More about `<NuxtPage>`: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page#nuxtpage

Comment: It opens new route. I want not nested route. I want to embed page into parent.

Comment: It doesn't. Check out the linked documentation. It says: "`NuxtPage` is required to display top-level or nested pages located in the `pages/` directory." You can also check out the examples in the documentation @eri.